# .Net - Best practice for element id's in repeating page sections

Tags: asp.net

I'm not sure how to boil this question down into a sensible single-line title. I'm also new to .Net.

I want to build a web-page version of an invoice, but I want each page of the invoice to flow down the page, not be paginated. The header of each section will be the same, but the line items and the footer will be different.

I've done this before by writing html to a stringbuilder and then outputting it to a literal control, but I think there must be a better way. I'm just having a hard time conceptualizing how to do something like this with server controls because of the fact that the ID's need to be unique.

Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Thanks!

Comment: Unsure if I understood the question correctly - I think what you are saying is that you have an issue with the ID of server controls - perhaps you meant because you want to create a "template"? If so, you can add your controls dynamically as needed (no "template").

Comment: Please show us screenshot/mockup regarding what you want to achieve.

Comment: To clarify, I'm trying to create a web page that displays a (potentially) multi-page invoice similar to the way a PDF is displayed in a PDF reader - as the you scroll drown, you see each page of the document - not paginated, where you click links or buttons view additional pages.

Comment: So, here is a quick example of what I want to create. If this doesn't make it clear, I'll create a mockup.
`A = invoice header
B = invoice line items
C = invoice footer`
As someone was scrolling through this webpage, looking at the "pages" of the invoice, they would see something like this:
`A-B-C, A-B2-C, A-B3-C, etc...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom control and give it some properties that you can modify how you want and add the same header and footer to the control. Then use it on your page how many times you would like. Check out tutorial here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/87474/ASP-NET-Custom-Control

Comment: Thanks! Here's a follow-up question about delivering data to the control: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13986984/load-data-into-a-usercontrol-as-control-properties-or-in-control-code-behind)