# Load data into a UserControl as control properties or in control code behind?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I'm building a UserControl that will repeat on the page a variable number of times. I'm trying to determine what the most efficient way to handle the data I will be loading into the Control. For the sake of simplicity, lets say it will be structured something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Header Item</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Body Item n</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Body Item n+1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Body Item n+2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>etc.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Footer Item</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

All of the data that will be loaded into this Control will come from a SQL Query. The Body items will be changing on every iteration of the control, but the Header and Footer items will be the same, and that is where I am trying to decide between a couple of options I can see.

1. Build the query into the code behind of the control itself and repeat it for every iteration of the control, or:
2. Query the data from the .aspx.cs page where the control will be used and deliver them as properties when the control is created.
3. ?

Option 1 seems very inefficient. If we were talking about only two items, then I might just be inclined to accept the inefficiency, but we're talking about a lot more.

Option 2 seems plausible, but I have no idea if that is actually any better than option 1.

Thoughts? Other options?

Comment: A repeater should do the job

Comment: Why don't you use a `Repeater`, `ListView` or `GridView`? You just have to set the `DataSource` accordingly and call `DataBind`.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean instead of a UserControl? I need a little more info about how those would be used as alternatives.

Comment: You can combine all these controls, especially Repeater with user controls. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496856/asp-net-loading-a-user-control-in-a-repeater

Comment: Use the repeater. Its Flexible enough for your needs.

Comment: Forgive me, but I'm having a hard time seeing how to use the Repeater suggestion to solve my problem. 

Are you suggesting using the Repeater to create each iteration of the control? If so, I still have to answer my original question of how to deliver the data to each control. Or are you suggesting using Repeater instead of the UserControl? In that case, I guess I would have to use a Repeater within a Repeater. Keep in mind that in my example, I'm repeating the entire table itself, not just the body section.

Comment: @brainbolt: Put the controls fpor your header, footer or body in a custom `UserControl`. You could create a `RowType` property as enum, then you can use it for every type. Switch the template according to it's type. Add the `UserControl` to the appropriate `GridView` templates: `HeaderTemplate`,`ItemTemplate`,`FooterTemplate`. You can use `RowDataBound` to set the properties of your UserControl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `Repeater` control

Have a look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater(v=vs.80).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server">

 <HeaderTemplate>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>Header Item</td>
   </tr>
 </HeaderTemplate>

 <ItemTemplate>
  <tr>
   <td>Body Item <%# Eval("Number") %></td>
  </tr>
 </ItemTemplate>

 <FooterTemplate>
   <tr>
    <td>Footer Item</td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </FooterTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```